# How to use Binder to deserialize to Kotlin's data class?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I use SpringBoot2.0.0.RELEASE, Kotlin 1.2.30, Java9.

I have the following configuration in the configuration file：

```
test:
  user:
    id: 111
    username: 111
    password: 111
    addtime: 2018-11-11 11:11:11
```

User.kt code is as follows:

```
data class User(
        val id: String,
        val username: String,
        val password: String,
        val addtime: LocalDateTime
) : Serializable
```

I try to read the configuration using the following code:

```
Binder.get(this.context.environment)
        .bind("test.user", User::class)
        .orElse(null)
```

However, it did not succeed and returned the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [demo.User]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No argument provided for a required parameter: parameter #0 id of fun <init>(kotlin.String, kotlin.String, kotlin.String, java.time.LocalDateTime): demo.User
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:179)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:124)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$Bean.lambda$getSupplier$0(JavaBeanBinder.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanSupplier.get(JavaBeanBinder.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.JavaBeanBinder$BeanProperty.lambda$getValue$0(JavaBeanBinder.java:303)
    ... 80 more
```

full error log: https://gist.github.com/Cat7373/174b0ddaf103b35062e7b03982f8cb38

How can I succeed? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this reference would help, try to add `@PersistentConstructor` annotation when define your data class: [Spring constructor annotations on Kotlin data class with default values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389720/spring-constructor-annotations-on-kotlin-data-class-with-default-values)
Or else, try setting the default value for each of your properties. Eg:

```
data class User(
    val id: String = "",
    val username: String = "",
    val password: String = "",
    val addtime: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
) : Serializable
```

Comment: Some parameters such as enum may not have suitable default parameters, So it may not be appropriate to do this